# Collada to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, webgl, three.js, collada

I try to display some Collada files with WebGL and Three.js. I tried with `THREE.ColladaLoader()` but it returns some materials errors.

I see it's possible to convert the file to JSON and then import it to WebGL.

I look around but didn't any solution to do that...

Any clue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>[COLLADA2Json](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/collada2json) may be what you are looking for.</strike>

edit:

gltf is a starndard now. (Json + binary). The converter is here: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/collada2gltf

Comment: Cool ! I think it didn't exist when i posted this question :)

Comment: But does it work?  I've finally got it to build, but the .json file it generates doesn't appear to have any vertex data in it :(

Comment: yes, it does work. Maybe you have encountered a bug? Please open an issue on the github page.

Comment: This link is broken.

Comment: its now a standard of its own  - https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF. the converter is here: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/collada2gltf

Answer (score 2):

One option could be to import the Collada file into Blender.

If it survives importing and still looks as expected, you could then export it from there using the [THREE.js's Blender exporter](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender) .

Answer (score 1):

Collada is notoriously difficult to parse. If you have one that doesn't parse, you'll have to write your own parser or fix one that you want to use. I gave up trying to use collada because of that, I'm now [using 3DS files](http://codeflow.org/entries/2011/nov/18/parsing-3d-file-formats/)

Comment: I found a nice solution, it's a plugin for Sketchup wich export directly to Three.js => https://github.com/timjb/sketchup-threejs